# Allow Other Application to choose Image from my application like Gallery

Tags: android

My app is a simple gallery app , where any user can make Images and save them to SdCard.
I have an activity in which all the images that user have created will be shown in a GridView.

Now what I want is my App to be shown in the Image Chooser list where gallery and other apps are shown.

I have implemented Intent Filters that are showing my app in the List,

> BUT what code should I write so that user can pick one image from my
>   gridview

.....[image]

```
  <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />

            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> BUT what code should I write so that user can pick one image from my gridview

You would write an `Activity` that has your `GridView`. When the user makes a choice, you would call `setResult()` to supply a `Uri` with the return value, containing the information documented for the `Intent` action that was used to trigger your activity. Then, you would call `finish()`, to close your activity and return control to whatever launched you.

The documentation for `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` has:

> Output: The URI of the item that was picked. This must be a content: URI so that any receiver can access it.

This `Uri` goes in the `Intent` that you pass to `setResult()`.

The documentation for `ACTION_PICK` has:

> Output: The URI of the item that was picked.

Hence, you can use the same code for populating the `Intent` for `setResult()` for both `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` and `ACTION_PICK`.

Comment: but how to write it ?

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setResult?
HOW?

Comment: @Dr.aNdRO: `setResult()` is a method on `Activity`. `finish()` is a method on `Activity`. This is also covered in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html and http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what I want is this :

```
Intent result = new Intent("com.example.RESULT_ACTION", Uri.parse("content://result_uri");
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
finish();
```

by using setResult like this we can send the data.